# Particles - Aligning particles to an SVG

Tags: particles, svg

My friend asks me for help about aligning **thousands of particles to an outline of an SVG.**

Tell me, what do I have to do?

Progress:

[image]

What he wants to achieve:

[image]

How it would go:

[image]

As my friend said: *"These are when the stars would stay in place in random seed, so the outline of the logo would form."*

Comment: Welcome ... What have you tried and where did you fail?

Comment: I'm asking that for a friend.

Comment: Welcome. What did the friend try, and where did they fail?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange Jeremy. This is not a "we do all the work for you "-platform, but a "we help you with what you tried so far"-platform. So just show us what you tried. Sorry- show us what your "friend" tried.

Comment: Hello, Chris! Well to be exact, my friend didn't fail and he just doesn't know how to make it. That's all I know.

Comment: Have a look at the [Harmonic Force Field](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/forces/force_fields/types/harmonic.html) and look for "keyed particles" tutorials like [this one](https://youtu.be/lPCs4XbGth8) to control the shape of particles.

Answer (score 2):

Does dots should appear in place (plus to add animated Camera movement backward to zoom-out) ...

[image]
*Example is SVG converted to Mesh (only outline), Extruded a bit to get side faces and added Particle System Emitted from Faces, Physics > None ...*

... or dots should fly from behind camera to front?

[image]
*Particles > **[Keyed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgmJsLcLXUI)** suggested by Blunder in comment.*

---

*No problem to extend answer or redirect you to somewhere for more details, when will be clear the particles motion.*

[image]