# Is it possible to transfer particles in the form of object after following a curved path (spiral or something)

Tags: particles, physics, animation-nodes

I want to gather particles in the form of object after riding it on path. how to do it?

I have two requirements:

1. Particle should follow our (user made) path (not random) and
2. After following our given path, i want them to rest in the shape of object
   There are lots of solutions and tutorials are available on above either one condition (but not both together)

So please only answer it if fulfils both.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219525/2214

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/238971/2214 ... same concept – search for Keyed particles

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid collisions of moving objects from point A to point B](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238960/how-to-avoid-collisions-of-moving-objects-from-point-a-to-point-b)

Comment: Geometry nodes ... https://youtu.be/w15hBuNVq6s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *Force Field* > **Curve Guide** (set *Free* like 0.8 so particles didn't end up at the end of curve)
- Final object > *Collision* (set some *Friction* and *Stickiness*)
- Inside place one *Empty* > *Force* and for second *Empty* > *Vortex* or **Turbulence** let particles fly around the object before they stack on surface
- To try keep distance between particles I tried to use in *Particle Properties > Force Field Settings >* enabled **Self Effect** and for *Type 1 >* **Charge** ...
- probably good to **disable Gravity** under *Scene Properties* or under *Particle Properties > Field Weights* ... so you don't have to fight with another force if you don't need it :)

[image]

It is all about forces so you would have to play a lot with settings ...

[image]

Notes:
There is a quite unnatural way to control speed particles on Curve Guide (for me), because speed is based on Particles LifeTime - at the end of lifetime particles has to reach the end of curve - long LifeTime = slow / short LifeTime = fast.

That could be fine if you don't need let particles live longer, but in your case it is an issue. That is why I used Free parametr that is described in [Mannual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/forces/force_fields/types/curve_guide.html) as ...

> **Free**
> Fraction of particle life time, that is not used for the curve.

That way it was easy to set, but hour of experimenting to discover.

Naturally (in terms of blender) I would expect the *Path Animation* to be a factor for speed, like for object animation (more of that because it is enabled by default ... btw disabling brings crash for me in 2.93) ... hmm, what to say.

Anyway another option to let particles follow a curve is to add *Curve* object and assign *Force Field > Type-Force,* **Shape-Curve** ... that works more natural for lifetime, but it was impossible for me to keep particles follow curve up to end of curve ... they just more and more accelerated out of curve path.

You can also use "final" object as Force Field and Collision at the same time ... but I wanted to separate them to better see what is causing issue.

If you would need to let particles spin around curve you can change **Tilt** parametr for each vertex of curve.

Comment: Now this is what i want, just one more thing (you can explain in just few words): after gathering particles on the object at the end, what force should i add to make random motion of particles within the volume of the object at the end ? thank you

Comment: For Randomisation you can try Turbulence force type instead of Vortex, but to be clear - all the methods stores particles on surface not inside. To get them in you would have to make a hole in mesh to feed particles into a volume ... or try to switch face Normals Inside ... that could cheat blender to let particles flow in but not out :) ... the most crazy thing with particles is cache that is not updated with setup change and I know only way to change number of particles +/-1 to get fresh cache. ... Or try to search geometry nodes if they could handle this task in more controllable way ... ?

Comment: ok, thank you very much.

Comment: ... it is a pain ... be prepared :) ... I edited the answer with some other notes good to mentioned

Comment: No problem, noted that :)